# jQuery rearrange/swap img src causes glitched reloading of photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm not sure what the best method for this would be, but I have to change the `src` attribute for several images on a page after they've loaded. I need to rearrange them so to speak.

In their original format, they are displayed like this:

```
1    5    9
2    6    10
3    7    11
4    8    12
```

I have written a jQuery function that rearranges them like this:

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
10   11   12
```

The rearranging works fine in theory, but when it comes time to actually change the `src` of the image it reloads the same image more than once and other strange behavior.

This is how I'm changing the `src`

```
$('img[src="image.png"]').attr('src', 'newimage.png');
```

Here is a fiddle containing the function I use to rearrange. The line above is on line 91.

https://jsfiddle.net/4o17Ldxu/

In the fiddle, click "generate swap list" and look in your browser console, you'll see that it tells you which images should be swapped where, everything there is perfect, but when you click the button again and click "now rearrange" it causes all the glitches.

Is there anyway to prevent this? Or is there a better way to go about swapping/rearranging images in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are not actually "swapping" images - you're setting a first image equal to a second, and leaving the second unchanged. For example, your code logs:

```
Swap Photo 4 with Photo 2
```

But what it is actually doing is:

```
$('img[src="image.png"]').attr('src', 'newimage.png');
```

After this operation completes, you will have two `<img>` tags in your page that will match the selector `img[src="newimage.png"]`.  In subsequent steps, if you try and select all images with `src="newimage.png"`, you'll end up replacing the `src` of multiple images.

Comment: Yes this appears to be the problem. I will rework the process, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept this answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: Absolutely, but please update your answer with actual code demonstrating a way to achieve the desired results in case future visitors need help with this as well. :) I believe I'm going to just add a numerical ID attribute to each element via jQuery and update the src based on that unchanging attribute, so you can use that method in your answer update if you wish.